# PHP. How to access specific database records and display it into a form

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

I am trying to build a site that will display every NFL team, sort them by conference and division, and then display various season stats for them.  I have a database built that has three tables: conference names, division names, and team info(name and season stats).  I cannot do anything different for the database since this is a class assignment and I can't have any hard coding.  I need to access the database to display all of this information into the HTML form that has been built.

I am having a hard figuring out how to pull specific information information from the database in order to display in the various parts of the table.  Here is some of the code I have so far.

```
    <?php        

    // connect to db
    include 'dbConnect.php';

    // Select statement
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM confnames, divnames teaminfo";
    $results = $pdo->query($sql);

    while($row = $results->fetch()) {
    ?>
            <tbody>

                                <tr>
                    <td class="team"><?= $row['teamName'] . $row['nickName'] ?></td>
                    <td>10</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td class="pct">1.000</td>
                    <td>6-0-0</td>
                    <td>4-0-0</td>
                    <td>3-0-0</td>
                    <td>8-0-0</td>
                    <td>355</td>
                    <td>212</td>
                    <td class="ptsGreen">+143</td>
                    <td class="streak">Won 10</td>
                                </tr>
    }
```

In this line:

```
<td class="team"><?= $row['teamName'] . $row['nickName'] ?></td>
```

I need to be able to pull one record from the teaminfo table and the teamName and nickName columns.  For example I have the first record in the teaminfo table set to the Green Bay teamName and the Packers nickName.  I need to display this specific information that specific spot and then do it again with the following team a little lower and so on and so forth until I have all 32 teams and their data displayed.

I have been having a hard time figuring out how I could do this without needing to re-write the sql statement and information before every single line where I need to display the information.  Do you guys have any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure that query is going to do what you want it to do. Select everything from everything?

Comment: I can help you build the queries but i need to know how is the database made. exactly on those three tables you want to retrieve data from

Comment: I need to be able to pull most information from the database. I need to get the divName from the divnames table and then be able to display that right next to the confName from the confnames table. I know how I can adjust my sql to pull specific records but I fear that I'll need to change my sql on every line that I need to display something. I need to pull data from the database for every <td> tag and display it in place of the numbers there now. I need to know if there is php to let me pick a specific record from the data I pull from the database without needing to re-write my sql constantly